# Android bug: Crop intent works on some devices

Tags: android, android-intent, android-file

Android bug: Crop intent works on some file managers.

Following code:

Launch intent to crop image from folder/file.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString());
        intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);

        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

2 versions of code crash differently on different devices, same Android version.

1st verison:

```
try 
    {
        bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), targetUri);

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Second version (works on other devices)

```
bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer of this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008623/android-mediastore-crop-function-how-to-make-selection-arrows-always-visible). The crop intent feature is apparently not present on every device and may be customized to behave differently. In cases like that you need to resort to implementing your own solution.

Comment: You should ***never*** blindly make use of internal APIs... always check to see if they exist before you make use of them, and know that not all devices will support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is part of the internal API so it is not guaranteed to be supported by all Android devices.

You will have to implement your own crop activity if you want it to be supported by all devices. At the very least you should implement some sort of fallback behavior if some device does not support the `Intent`. **PLEASE DON'T FORGET TO DO THIS!!** :)

And by the way, if I recall correctly, the Samsung Galaxy implements its own Media/Gallery app, so that is why it is failing to recognize the Intent.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Some devices don't support Intent? isn't that a bit crazy?

Comment: It's not that they don't "support" the intent... it's more like they "re-defined it". Android is open source which means that companies like Samsung and HTC can take the source code and customize the UI, remove certain apps, make their own apps, etc. This is why nothing from Google's internal source code is never something you can rely on... because it's not guaranteed to stay the same for *all* devices. On the other hand, the public SDK is guaranteed to work no matter what. The public SDK is an abstraction above the internal APIs, which means you can always trust it to work.

Comment: This is also why it takes so long for some devices to upgrade to newer versions of Android (i.e. most devices *still* haven't been upgraded to ICS yet)... because companies like Verison and Samsung spend an extra 6-12 months modifying the OS to their needs.

Comment: That's kinda annoying. So the should I make my own crop class? (Know any examples I can simple feed URI into?)

Comment: i'm not aware of any third party libraries that do this (although I admit, I only did a quick google search for "android crop third party apps" and gave up relatively quickly). Maybe you can find something online that supports it. Worst case scenario is your implement a fallback behavior if your app doesn't support the internal API... that way at least *some* of the devices will be able to crop. This is obviously not what you want but again... it's a worst case scenario if you don't find anything.

Comment: How would I implement a fall back on that? I've noticed it's some file managers that don't crop and some that do.

Comment: you'd have to use package manager and check to see if the package `com.android.camera` is installed on the device... something like that at least. sorry, i'm in a rush right now, but let me know in a few hours if you figure it out and i can get back to you lol.